# How to use domain for WSO2 AM 2.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

As per the below picture, it showed that generated endpoints use internal IPs rather than domain name. I was just wondering how to make it adapt domain (connectionnz.cloudapp.net).

[image: picture]

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the endpoints in api-manager.xml which resides in wso2am-2.1.0/repository/conf location.

In the **APIGateway** tag change the **GatewayEndpoint** as follows.

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://connectionnz.cloudapp.net,https://connectionnz.cloudapp.net</GatewayEndpoint>
```

**Note:** If you are running a distributed setup change the above configurations in Publisher and Store nodes.